# Extracting month to column from year-month pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to select the month from the lines where the year and month are and put it in the column.

from this df:

```
2018-01 33651.64
2018-02 24869.52
2018-03 41602.48
2018-04 41011.95
2019-01 64912.46
2019-02 77526.91
2019-03 163113.66
2019-04 74833.04
```

to somthing like this df:

```
            1        2         3        4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
2017        0        0         0        0
2018 33651.64 24869.52  41602.48 41011.95......
2019 64912.46 77526.91 163113.66 64912.46......
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, but perhaps the one that retains the most information is to first ensure your date column is in `datetime` format, extract the year and month, and then pivot the whole dataframe on `year` and `month`. Specifically, you could run (I'm assuming the column names):

```py
df['month'] = df.date.apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.month
df['year'] = df.date.apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.year

df.pivot(index='year', columns='month', values='num')
```

This will turn your dataframe into:

```
month   1           2           3           4
year                
2018    NaN         24869.52    41602.48    41011.95
2019    64912.46    77526.91    163113.66   74833.04
```

Note that `df` still has the `date` column (full year-month), but you're only using `year` and `month` columns in the pivot. Also, if your `date` column is already a `datetime` type, you can skip the first transformation with `apply(pd.to_datetime)`.

Comment: show this error : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: That's because your 'date' column is probably not called literally `date`. Try replacing the column names with the real ones from your dataframe.

Comment: definitely i have issue with extraction when i try this: df2['month'] = df2['date'].dt. month show in column month NaN

Comment: @Roman What is the name of the columns in your dataframe? If you run `df.columns`? If it's an empty list, you should name them (for example like `df.columns = ['date', 'num']`) before proceeding to the next steps. Also, what `dtype` is your column to begin with? I'm assuming str? You can do `df.dtypes` to check.